# Full disk encryption on Debian servers?

Tags: partition, encryption, reboot

I installed debian 10 on my old pc (i386)
using the full disk encryption option from installer.

When I boot it nothing starts until i give the
decryption password at the screen.

Thus i cannot ssh to the computer after a boot,
I do need physical access.

Now some questions:

1) Can i disable the encryption passwd request after boot?

2) There should be a kind of "merge" of user login and
disk decryption in one action (strange thoughts  :-),
But my only option here seems to be standard installation
with later encryption of the home partition, right?

2) Why the full disk encryption option from the installer
does not allow me to manually set partition sizes?
(I observed it at the later ubuntu versions as well)

Thx for your thoughts!!!

Comment: 1) If you disable the password request, what is the purpose of encryption, since anyone would have access to your data by just booting on the disk? 2) There are ways to encrypt your home folder, but they seem to be geared towards graphical desktop users, things are possibly more manual with an SSH session.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple methods to overcome this limitation. Here are three of them (the 3rd one is really complex to grasp and integrate).

- have a device, like an USB key, holding a passphrase to decode LUKS's master key. Then debian can use automatically this key at boot with the `passdev` keyscript, to add in `/etc/crypttab`, as described in [`/usr/share/doc/cryptsetup-run/README.Debian.gz`](https://salsa.debian.org/cryptsetup-team/cryptsetup/blob/38f1d5b2d929e9e09900f8b56cae8056f0f7ba59/debian/README.Debian#L139). If the USB key is physically stolen, then passphrase and encryption is compromised. It can be added upon your current installation.
- Use remote unlocking with [dropbear](https://packages.debian.org/stable/dropbear-initramfs), which has documentation in [`/usr/share/doc/dropbear-initramfs/README.initramfs`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/dropbear/blob/debian/2018.76-5/debian/README.initramfs): you can ssh to the system in booting stage, just to unlock LUKS master key. If the server is physically tampered with and its boot altered, then the remotely typed passphrase and encryption is compromised. It can be added upon your current installation. With some tweaking, it might perhaps be possible to have both the previous method and this method available at the same time (normally dropbear is available concurrently with the usual keyboard input).
- And just to mention it, should you be interested, probably the most secure method, requiring a complex infrastructure, usually to support a farm of encrypted servers deployed at an untrusted datacenter: [Clevis](https://github.com/latchset/clevis), usually used along [Tang](https://github.com/latchset/tang), which have been developped at Redhat (where more documentation is available: [RHEL7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-policy-based_decryption), [RHEL8](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/configuring-automated-unlocking-of-encrypted-volumes-using-policy-based-decryption_security-hardening)). Both [are](https://packages.debian.org/stable/clevis) [packaged](https://packages.debian.org/stable/tang) on Debian, but the integration is probably very complex. It's based upon features like [Shamir's Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing), where the secret is distributed among multiple places and other similar features to keep the secret... secret. It's aiming at automatic remote decryption for LUKS, while being more resilient against security compromission.

About the last question: you should be able to choose the size, but must set up things manually without assisted mode. There are also some drawbacks in the Debian installer: once the step of partitioning is done with LUKS and LVM, it's difficult to change mind and alter it (and then often faster to start over the installation). You could have more options available if you choose to change the priority of questions asked in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing: 
1) you cannot disable password request at the boot <- your disk is encrypted and OS cannot continue without the decrypting. It is not similar to disable the password request while entering KDE or GNOME, while in this case the system is running giving you a chance to login your preffered user automaticaly by inserting your saved credentials.

2) user login comes into play when the OS is fully started! Is is recommended to protect your user data (in /home dir) only.

the next 2) If you asked for full disk encryption, your disk is encrypted as a whole. The partitions are created on the encrypted disk, hence there is no reason to set the partition size before the encryption.